Which is correct grammatically ? "Give in your will." or "Give, in your will"
"Give in your will."
or
"Give, in your will"
The context is one of giving money in your will, rather than handing in your will to someone. It would be the title of an article. The article would be about encouraging people to give money to a charity in their will.
The sentence is an instruction, so I feel, the the word Give should have a comma or a colon after it.


Give, in your will
Give: in your will


There is an oddness to Give simply followed by in, in this context. Am I correct?

Give a full sentence.

What else can you do in your will?

@EdwinAshworth - Good point, but actually exclude people, I think.

Alan, I unintentionally I broke one of our minor rules, in using a comment to offer an answer. Since you regard it positively, I've turned my comment into the full deal, which allows you to award it a "tick" (i.e. to formally accept it) if you think it resolves your question. I'll delete my comment as no longer necessary. :-)

The title of your question is misinformed. This isn't a matter of grammar, it's a matter of style. There are common conventions, and there are style manuals, but there's no definitively correct answer, other than the missive to choose the punctuation that enables your reader to quickly understand your intent.
Is there a reason for such parsimony in your title? FWIW, I'd either change "give" to "donate", or add some words, e.g.

"Be sure to give, in your will"

or (better)...

"In your will, be sure to give."


Instead of give, I would suggest leave...
For example:
'Leave a (Charitable) Legacy'

legacy n. a gift of personal property or money to a beneficiary
(legatee) of a will. While technically legacy does not include real
property (which is a "devise"), legacy usually refers to any gift from
the estate of one who has died. It is synonymous with the word
"bequest."
legacy, legal definition; law.com

Of course, 'leave a legacy' has a broader meaning. See example of usage (https://www.goodlifeproject.com/articles/how-to-leave-a-legacy/). And leave/left has various meanings and connotations. See usage in given context:

What Is a Legacy in a Will?
In simple terms, a legacy is a gift that you leave to someone in your will. Many people decide to leave legacies in their will to loved ones or a charity close to their heart. The people who receive the legacies are called “beneficiaries”.
(Emphasis added.)
[phrsolicitors]

Or you could 'Will the Change' (just what's left over, a residual legacy). Titles are flexible.
